# Is there a fix for Corsair Link

Tags: command-line, drivers, graphics, hdmi, display-resolution

been trying to create new resolution output mode using:

```
    sudo xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"  84.75 1360 1432 1568 1776  768 771 781 798 -hsync+vsync
```

This is what I get:

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19

I am new to Linux and need help fixing this so i can see my entire screen.
also just to make sure the command to add if i can get it to create is:

```
    sudo xrandr --addmode 1368x768_60.00
```

Yes i have tried running without the "sudo" with the same results.
the screen i am using is an Emerson LC320EM1F connected to my desktop with an HDMI from graphics card, no hookup on board for HDMI. Again I am new to Linux and could really use the help.

Note: Here is whats in my build:

-Asus M5A97 LE R2.0

-AMD Athlon(tm) II 170u Processor

-GEFORCE GTX 960

-H100i GTX

-COOLMAX ZU Series 700W 80 PLUS Bronze Certified Modular Power Supply

-COOLMASTER HAF 912

Comment: forgot to change the header on question. not worried bout corsair atm. worried bout getting resolution solution